# trying to create a "bump" chart in ChartJS, how to control where the lines change direction

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to create a bump chart in ChartJS, similar to this:
[image: example of a bump chart]

I have got the icons I want appearing using [points on a LineGraph](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/point-styling.html) and supplying a [pointstyle Image](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#types) but the lines themselves go from the point, not a controllable offset (to make it look more like the example).

Is it possible using existing ChartJS functionality, or an existing plugin?